# Why is memory increased so much from the 2nd multiprocessing blocks?

Tags: python, ubuntu, memory, multiprocessing

My code is using multiprocessing in two block as below:

```
data_directory = 'test/'
id_map, all_data = create_id(data_directory, channel)
create_relationship(id_map, all_data, channel)

def create_id(dir_path, channel):
        dir_path = os.path.join(abspath, dir_path)
        files = [join(dir_path, f) for f in listdir(dir_path)]

        id_map = {}
        all_data = []

        process_pool = Pool(multiprocessing.cpu_count())
        results = process_pool.starmap(process_file, zip(files, repeat(channel)))
        for result in results:
            id_map.update(result[0])
            all_data.append(result[1])

    return (id_map, all_data)
```

This is the first block which uses mulitiprocessing to process files in parallel. The results are collected in the id_map and all_data list. The detail of the process_file is omited, which just processes each file and return the id_map, and current data, as shown in result[0], result[1]

On my 40 cores Linux, if I just run this block of code, it looks all normal. Many processes are started and CPUs are running 90%-100% each. Each process takes a little memory, and the total consumed is about 20G. At the end of this processing, about 100G memory is still free.

Now next step, this function takes the id_map and all_data produced from the first step as input, and do more work:

```
def create_relationship(id_map, all_data, channel):
        logger.info('id_map size ... {}'.format(len(id_map)))
        logger.info('all_data size ... {}'.format(len(all_data)))

        process_pool = Pool(20)
        process_pool.starmap(self.process_data, zip(all_data, repeat(channel), repeat(id_map)))
```

I only specified 20 cores, though the machine has 40 cores to process the list of all_data. The implementation of process_data is outlined as below:

```
def process_data(df_data, channel, id_map):

    # Only process identifier file
    node_df = df_data[0]
    node_file = df_data[1]
    node_label = df_data[2]

    node_df = node_df.replace(np.nan, '', regex=True)

    columns = list(node_df)
    for label in columns:
        ...

        relations = []

        ...
        
        if relations:
            # To write the relations to csv file for this 'label'
            # relation_output_file is str, the output file path
            relation_output_file =create_relation_output_file_name(node_file)
            rel_df = pd.DataFrame(relations)
            rel_df = rel_df.drop_duplicates()
            rel_df.to_csv(relation_output_file, sep='\t', index=False)
```

Although I skipped more details of process_data, it doesn't create any new objects. It created a relations list for each dataframe (file), but once it's done with outputting to the csv file, this variable went out of scope, memory is released.

What I observed in linux is that, before create_relationship() is called, the multiprocesing runs well and memory consumption looks normal. At the end there are about 100G free. But once it starts to call create_relationship(), memory for each process suddenly increases to 17G, and the consumption gradually increases further. Because of that, in the second Pool() setting, I can't use multiprocessing.cpu_count(), because after some time all memory will be consumed and all python processes will be stopped but only one is left. I specified 20 or 30 cores to be used, and. the program runs fine.

I don't understand this behavior, because in the 2nd function, nothing new created and accumulated. The 'relations' list is temporarily created but should be gone after each dataframe is processed and the result is output to csv file.

Is that because in the same program, two places use multiprocessing, which isn't good? The memory consumption looks weird between the two function calls.

Comment: Does to_csv() close the file handle?  You may have to close it yourself.  It's possible you're drowning in File Buffers.

Comment: No. I thought it is automatically closed for dataframe.

Comment: Is `relationship_output_file` a string or a file handle?  Hard to tell from the code.  The documentation doesn't say what happens, and I can believe that if it's a file handle, it might keep it open.  I'm struggling to find something else bad with your code.

Comment: I updated, it is str, the output file path.

Comment: Actually, you bring up a good point!  You're creating two separate Process pools.  You should probably use `with Process(<count>) as process_pool:` so that each  pool gets cleaned up when you're done.  Or re-use the same process pool both times.

Comment: What's the syntax? I am using  Pool(), not Process().

Comment: Strange, I changed to 'with multiprocessing.Pool(multiprocessing.cpu_count()) as pool', but memory usage pattern didn't change at all!

Comment: Sorry.  Process was a typo on my part.  You changed both pools?

Comment: Yes, i changed both but nothing changed. Then I only created the first pool and pass it to the next function. In this case, the memory doesn't increase much, but it can only use about 10-15 cores at maximum, no matter I specified 30 cores or multiprocessing.cpu_count() for all cores. Because of that, the overall speed doesn't change much than I created two pools. The first function can make use of all cores and it runs much faster. Don't know why in the 2nd case only part of cores are used.